# Replacing Paths in a File with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

So, I have this text file containing a few paths to files. Those paths need to be partially replaced. This needs to be case insensitive, so I tried doing this with Regex.

A part of the file looks like this:

```
PATH1         = d:\Software\system\SETUP\folder1
PATH2         = d:\Software\system\SETUP\folder2
PATH3         = d:\Software\system\SETUP
```

The first part: `d:\Software\system` needs to be replace with `c:\Software\system`

I tried this with the following code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

string pattern = "d:\\Software\\system";
string replace = "C:\\Software\\system";

string newText = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, replace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, newText);
```

This however does not  change anything in the file. I also used breakpoints to analize the value of newText after the Replace line, and it does not have anything to do with the writing of the file.

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Use four consecutive backslashes instead of two. One backslash escapes another.

Comment: Use `Regex.Esape(pattern)`. Or just use plain `String.Replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Regex.Escape` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.100).aspx) that will escape your literal pattern:

Here is a [testing code](https://ideone.com/D8tM9Y):

```
var text = @"PATH1         = d:\Software\system\SETUP\folder1
PATH2         = d:\Software\system\SETUP\folder2
PATH3         = d:\Software\system\SETUP";
string pattern = "d:\\Software\\system";
string replace = "C:\\Software\\system";

string newText = Regex.Replace(text, Regex.Escape(pattern), replace.Replace("$", "$$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Console.WriteLine(newText);
```

Another way is to use [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) that you need to use with [`CompareMethod.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `Text`
>   Optional. **Results in string comparisons based on a case-insensitive text sort order determined by your system's locale**.
>   This type of comparison is useful if your strings contain all text characters, and you want to compare them taking into account alphabetic equivalences such as case insensitivity and closely related letters. For example, you might want to consider A and a to be equal, and Ä and ä to come before B and b.

Code:

```
var newText = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(text, 
               pattern, 
               replace, 
               Compare: Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern \S means Not white space and \s means white space. You need to make the backslashes literal by escaping them with their own backslashes:

So either:

```
string pattern = @"d:\\Software\\system";
```

Or:

```
string pattern = "d:\\\\Software\\\\system";
```

Answer (score 0):

For file paths you can convert path, pattern and replace `.ToUpper()` and then do a normal `string newPath = path.Replace(pattern, replace);`

**P.S.** If you the resulting path string casing matters — the `Regex.Escape` solution is better.